# add loading spinner to iframeSizer

Tags: javascript, css, iframe

Hi I'm using the the [iframeSizer](https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer) to load iframes dynamically.  On the parent page I'm currently implementing this code to load the spinning preloader image with css:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//example.com/iframeResizer.min.js"></script> 

<style>

iframe{width:100%} 
.holds-the-iframe { 
    background:url(//example.com/preloader.gif) center center no-repeat;  
         }
</style> 

<div class="holds-the-iframe">
<iframe src="http://example.com/iframed-content-url" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div> 

<script>iFrameResize()</script>
```

The problem with this is if there is a transparent background on the iframe content, the spinner shows through.  iFrameResizer has a bodyBackground option but that changes the entire body, not just the content inside of the iframe.

Any thoughts on how to improve this?  Is there a way with CSS or JS to remove the spinner node completely after the iframe initially is loaded?  Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen this option: https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer#bodybackground ?

Answer (score 2):

The plugin allows you to use options,
one of them is [bodyBackground](https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer#bodybackground) and accepts a `String` value.

so you could perhaps give this a try:

```
iFrameResize({
    bodyBackground : "rgba(0,0,0,1) url(preloader.gif) 50% no-repeat"
});
```

Comment: The problem is bodyBackground changes the entire parent page's body, not just the div holding the iframe.

Comment: @Acyra the spec says: *`Override the body background style in the iFrame.`* so you should file a bug or perhaps find it in your code...

Comment: Yeah I think there's a conflict with iframe width:100% and changing the background.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the feedback.  My simple solution was to just put the spinner as a background in the actual iframe css, rather than in a wrapper.  Then the content overwrites it upon load.